# Why does my virtualenv inherit the system's old environment variables?

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtualenv

When I created my virtual environment, it inherited all of the environment variables that were currently on my Windows machine. I have since changed many of those variables, and my virtual environment is now stuck with the old values. **How can I change the environment variables within my virtual environment?**

Comment: Which environment variables in particular?

Comment: I specifically need to update the `GDAL_DATA` variable. 
It is currently: `C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\gdal-data`
I need to set it to: `C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.3\\gdal-data`

Comment: A basic virtualenv setup should not set environment variables outside of several having to do with python and the environment itself.  Is GDAL_DATA being set in your venv_path\Scripts\activate.bat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that the reason my virtual environment's environment variables were keeping their previous values was because I was still in the same terminal session. Restarting my terminal fixed the issue.